# On rank of a block matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Supposing determinants of $A_i=\begin{bmatrix}a_i&b_i\\c_i&d_i\end{bmatrix}$ from $i=1$ to $4$ and $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ are $0$ over $\Bbb F_p$ for large $p$. Then can rank of $\begin{bmatrix}aA_1&bA_2\\cA_3&dA_4\end{bmatrix}$ over $\Bbb F_p$ for large $p$ be $4$?

Please take $$a_i\neq b_i\neq c_i\neq d_i$$$$a\neq b\neq c\neq d$$ which is my situation and no entries are $0$.

What can be its maximum rank?

Comment: Perhaps you want to give some restrictions on $p?$ For example, if $p=2,$ then clearly there is only one non-zero element in $\mathbb F_p...$

Answer (score 1):

Denote $E_{ij}$ the matrix that has $(i, j)$ entry $1$ and all other entries zero. Setting $A_1 = E_{11}, A_2 = E_{21}, A_3 = E_{22}, A_4 = E_{12}$ and $A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$ yields the (permutation) matrix
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 \\
& & 1 \\
\hline
& & & 1 \\
& 1
\end{array}
\right) .
$$

Comment: thank you very much I do not want $0$ entried matrix.

Comment: You should specify such constraints when you first pose the question.

Comment: sorry is this hard?